# How to Automate the publishing of Infopath form as Administrator Approved Templates?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

Is there a way to automate the process of publishing Administrator-Approved InfoPath Templates?  I am tired of having to go through the lengthly, tedious process every time I want to make a tiny change to a form.

I want be able to save my infopath file (in infopath) and then run a command, perhaps a batch file or commandline of sorts to:

1. Publish the form as an Administrator Approved Template to the right "release" location
2. Upload the Form Template into SCA.

Any ideas?

Comment: "every time" is true only for Infopath 2007. 2010 introduced sandboxed solutions that permit to avoid administrator-approved templates and to publish Infopath form templates directly without uploading and approving them.

Comment: But I still have to go through the steps of publishing as and administrator-approved template, then I have to upload the form template.  Am I missing something quicker?

Comment: Publish as a content type to a document library, not as an administrator approved form?

Comment: BGM, direct publishing, in case of sandbox solutions, does not require steps of uploading the form template and its administrator approval. Also, the latter is only for web-based forms. This is according to docs. But in reality there are undocumented discrepancies between reality and theory

Comment: What do you mean by "direct publishing"?  My forms all have code-behind and open in the browser.  I tried the "Quick Publish" function in Infopath, but that doesn't work.  I wish for a set of commandlines, or a powershell script or something.  I like scripts.